# NSItemProvider[URL] - how to COPY with drag&Drop instead of MOVE?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsitemprovider

I have implemented function that returns NSItemProvider

```
func dragOutsideWnd(url: URL?) -> NSItemProvider {
    if let url = url {
        TheApp.appDelegate.hideMainWnd()
        
        let provider = NSItemProvider(item: url as NSSecureCoding?, typeIdentifier: UTType.fileURL.identifier as String)
        
        provider.suggestedName = url.lastPathComponent
        //provider.copy()// This doesn't work :)
        
        //DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //    TheApp.appDelegate.hideMainWnd()
        //}
        
        return provider
    }
    
    return NSItemProvider()
}
```

and I have use it this way:

```
.onDrag {
   return dragOutsideWnd(url: itm.url)
}
```

This drag&drop action performs file MOVE action to any place of **FINDER/HDD.**

But how to perform COPY action?

Comment: Is AppKit's `NSDragOperation` of any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember Drag&Drop is actually implemented with `NSPasteboard`.

I have written an example for you:
[GitHub](https://github.com/kasimok/73754718/blob/main/README.md)

[image]

Now the key to your questions:

**To control dragging behavior(your window is the source):**

Draggable objects conform to the `NSDraggingSource` protocol, so check the first method of the protocol:

```
@MainActor func draggingSession(
    _ session: NSDraggingSession,
    sourceOperationMaskFor context: NSDraggingContext
) -> NSDragOperation
```

As the [method doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdraggingsource/1416000-draggingsession)suggests, return different `NSDragOperation` in this delegation method. That includes: "Copy","Move", "Link", etc.

**To control dropping behavior(your window is the destination):**

NSView that accepts drop conforms to the `NSDraggingDestination` protocol, so you need to override the draggingEntered(_:) method by adding this code inside the Destination**View** class implementation:

```
override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation 
{
   var allow = true
   //.copy .move, see more options in NSDragOperation, up to you.
   return allow ? .copy : NSDragOperation() 
}
```

More info form [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/drag_and_drop)

For swiftUI, a simple show case [SwiftUI Showcase](https://github.com/filipvabrousek/RunUI/blob/0c73c7970275022c09fce6f27c21460a356de57b/Examples/Drag-Drop.md)

**Further Reading**: RayWenderlich.com has a detailed tutorial [Drag and Drop Tutorial for macOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1016-drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-macos) tutorial for you(needs a little swift upgrade).

Comment: destination is finder or any another app... so I cannot override method in destionation. read function name: "dragOutsideWnd"  or "This drag&drop action performs file MOVE action to any place of FINDER/HDD" in question asked :) But thanks for reply

Comment: Appkit solution is also ok, I think. But I need to drag (copy) url from my app to outside app

Comment: @Andrew___Pls_Support_UA, I edited the answer, it's `draggingSession(
    _ session: NSDraggingSession,
    sourceOperationMaskFor context: NSDraggingContext
) -> NSDragOperation ` method in your case

Comment: Thanks, will check tomorrow your answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: Created a github example for you. Take a look, Bro!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Today will check your github and will mark it as correct answer! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to answer of kakaiikaka!

The following solution works in swiftUI:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func asDragable(url: URL, tapAction: @escaping () -> () , dTapAction: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
        self.background {
            DragDropView(url: url, tapAction: tapAction, dTapAction: dTapAction)
        }
    }
}

struct DragDropView: NSViewRepresentable  {
    let url: URL
    let tapAction: () -> ()
    let dTapAction: () -> ()
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        return DragDropNSView(url: url, tapAction: tapAction, dTapAction: dTapAction)
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) { }
}

class DragDropNSView: NSView, NSDraggingSource  {
    let url: URL
    let tapAction: () -> ()
    let dTapAction: () -> ()
    
    let imgMove: NSImage = NSImage(named: "arrow.down.doc.fill_cust")!
    
    init(url: URL, tapAction: @escaping () -> (), dTapAction: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.url = url
        self.tapAction = tapAction
        self.dTapAction = dTapAction
        
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func draggingSession(_ session: NSDraggingSession, sourceOperationMaskFor context: NSDraggingContext) -> NSDragOperation {
        return mustBeMoveAction ? .move : .copy
    }
}

extension DragDropNSView: NSPasteboardItemDataProvider {
    func pasteboard(_ pasteboard: NSPasteboard?, item: NSPasteboardItem, provideDataForType type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) {
        // If the desired data type is fileURL, you load an file inside the bundle.
        if let pasteboard = pasteboard, type == NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL {
            pasteboard.setData(url.dataRepresentation, forType:type)
        }
    }
    
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
        
        tapAction()
        
        if event.clickCount == 2 {
            dTapAction()
        }
    }
    
    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        //1. Creates an NSPasteboardItem and sets this class as its data provider. A NSPasteboardItem is the box that carries the info about the item being dragged. The NSPasteboardItemDataProvider provides data upon request. In this case a file url
        let pasteboardItem = NSPasteboardItem()
        pasteboardItem.setDataProvider(self, forTypes: [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL])
        
        var rect = imgMove.alignmentRect
        rect.size = NSSize(width: imgMove.size.width/2, height: imgMove.size.height/2)
        
        //2. Creates a NSDraggingItem and assigns the pasteboard item to it
        let draggingItem = NSDraggingItem(pasteboardWriter: pasteboardItem)
        
        draggingItem.setDraggingFrame(rect, contents: imgMove) // `contents` is the preview image when dragging happens.
        
        //3. Starts the dragging session. Here you trigger the dragging image to start following your mouse until you drop it.
        beginDraggingSession(with: [draggingItem], event: event, source: self)
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////
///HELPERS
///////////////////////////////////////
extension DragDropNSView {
    var dragGoingOutsideWindow: Bool {
        guard let currEvent = NSApplication.shared.currentEvent else { return false }
        
        if let rect = self.window?.contentView?.visibleRect,
           rect.contains(currEvent.locationInWindow)
        {
            return false
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    var mustBeMoveAction: Bool {
        guard let currEvent = NSApplication.shared.currentEvent else { return false }
        
        if currEvent.modifierFlags.check(equals: [.command]) {
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    }
}

extension NSEvent.ModifierFlags {
    func check(equals: [NSEvent.ModifierFlags] ) -> Bool {
        var notEquals: [NSEvent.ModifierFlags] = [.shift, .command, .control, .option]
        
        equals.forEach{ val in notEquals.removeFirst(where: { $0 == val }) }
        
        var result = true
        
        equals.forEach{ val in
            if result {
                result = self.contains(val)
            }
        }
        
        notEquals.forEach{ val in
            if result {
                result = !self.contains(val)
            }
        }
        
        return result
    }
}
```

usage:

```
FileIcon()
    .asDragable( url: recent.url, tapAction: {}, dTapAction: {})
```

this element will be draggable and perform `MOVE` in case `.command` key pressed.

And will perform `COPY` in another case

Also it performs drag action only outside widndow. But it's easy to change.